# matlab debugger no longer displays output

Tags: matlab, debugging, command-window

MATLAB used to output the line number and the computation performed at that line number when I used the debugger. Now, as I step through each command, it just outputs a single `K>>`. I didn't change any settings, so what is going on? How can I get the display back to normal?  By the way, I am using using OS X.

Comment: There is no solution to that question, hence I asked it again.

Comment: Then you should mention that in your question and save others trouble. However, the answer to that question unfortunately looks like it *is* the solution –you don't get line numbers unless you downgrade to an older version of Matlab. Any potential solution would likely require mucking about with undocumented stuff for the command window / debugger. Also, please edit your question to indicate what version you were using that had the line numbers.

Comment: look, I was just using the same version of MATLAB (R2014b) yesterday and not experiencing these issues.  In lecture, the professor used debugging and his machine gave the output I am looking for.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the expected behavior. A picture would be ideal if you can find one. Do you mean that the `K>>` cursor itself gets modified to include the line number? Is the output any different from what is displayed when one sets a breakpoint in the Editor and types `dbstep` in the Command Window?

Comment: Entering `dbstep` in the command window is very similar to what I am looking for.  However, I have to enter `dbstep` every time.  Prior to today, I could just hit the 'step' command and the information displayed by `dbstep` - which includes line number and the code on that line - also displayed the value of the variable on that line.  So `dbstep` displays e.g. `10     for jj=1:c`, but I am looking for the output that displays e.g. `10    ii=3  for ii=1:c`.

Comment: By "hit the 'step' command", I assume you mean the Step button in the control bar?  I'm using R2014b on OS X. My debugger control bar buttons don't print out the line number like `dbstep` does. However, pressing command-shift-O while the Command Window has focus (in front as a separate window) does work like `dbstep`, but not when the Editor has focus (maybe because line numbers are shown in the Editor itself). You should still edit and clarify your original question, but you may have better luck asking this sort of thing at [MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/).